# (Porting to Android) In the Android NDK, how can I get the OpenGL context in my current thread?

Tags: multithreading, opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm porting some code to Android from iOS.

In iOS, you can make an OpenGL context current in the current thread like so:

```
[EAGLContext *aContext=[viewController getContext];
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:aContext];
```

And now suddenly you can use OpenGL in this thread without a problem.

What is the equivalent way to do this in Android, using the NDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`eglMakeCurrent()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/sdk/docs/man/html/eglMakeCurrent.xhtml):

> `eglMakeCurrent` binds `context` to the current rendering thread and to the `draw` and `read` surfaces.